# Unit test Dom Manipulation Service

Tags: angularjs

How can i Unit test the below service in Angular using Jasmine

```
angular.module('xyz')
    .service('noteCardDisplay', function () {

      function waitForDialog() {
        var dialogWrapper, dialogModal;
        dialogWrapper = angular.element('.modal-content').parent().parent();
        dialogWrapper.css('height', 475);
        dialogWrapper.css('width', 650);
        dialogWrapper.css('margin-left', 300);
        dialogWrapper.css('margin-top', 200);
        dialogModal = angular.element('.modal-content').parent();
        dialogModal.css('margin', 0);
      }

      return {
        waitForDialog: waitForDialog
      };

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your service deals with DOM elements, then you should use `$compile` to create DOM fragments for testing purposes. Then you can verify certain values of the attributes using `angular.element.attr`.

This will look smth like this:

```
it('div should have title attribute', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  $rootScope.title = 'new title';
  element = $compile('<div title="{{title}}"></div>')($rootScope);
  $rootScope.$digest();
  expect(element.attr('title')).not.toBe('');
  expect(element.attr('title')).toBe(undefined);
}));
```